# Google Docs API set font background to transparent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

How do you set the background color to be transparent with the Google Docs API. I can set the background to a specific color, aka "#aa00aa". However, I am not sure how to set it to transparent. For example, say you have:

```
function myTypes() {
    var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
    if (selection) {
    var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];

        // Only modify elements that can be edited as text; skip images and other non-text elements.
        if (element.getElement().editAsText) {
            var text = element.getElement().editAsText();

            // Edit the selected part of the element, or the full element if it's completely selected.
            if (element.isPartial()) {
                text.setFontSize(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), 10);
                text.setFontFamily(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "Consolas");
                text.setForegroundColor(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "#cc0cc");
                text.setBackgroundColor(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "#aa00aa");
            } else {
                text.setFontSize(10);
                text.setFontFamily("Consolas");
                text.setForegroundColor("#cc00cc");
                text.setBackgroundColor("#aa00aa");
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that use can just use the term "null" without quotes.

```
text.setBackgroundColor(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is using rgba codes, e.g.

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

You can set the transparency with the last criterium; a 0 meaning entirely transparent and 1 meaning opaque. Thus you should do something such as the following to render your background transparent:

```
text.setBackgroundColor("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
```